# How to get list from MySql in python?

Tags: python

I am nex to python and want to retrieve values from MySQL into a list in python 3.x:

```
curb.execute("SELECT URL FROM test")
URLs_old = curb.fetchall()
```

results in:

```
[('https://www.test.de',), ('https://www.bla.de',)]
```

while I would need:

```
['https://www.test.de', 'https://www.bla.de']
```

How can the later one be achived?

Answer (score 2):

You can always do

```
lst1 = [('https://www.test.de',), ('https://www.bla.de',)]
lst2 = [item for tpl in lst1 for item in tpl]
print(lst2)
# ['https://www.test.de', 'https://www.bla.de']
```

There might exist functions that return a list immediately though (haven't checked).

Comment: That seems to work as it looks like the list I need, but Python returns the error when I try using it: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'". Context is scrapy rules, where I try to add URLs I want to deny:         Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=['^.*\\d+/[a-z0-9-]+\.html$'],
                deny=[URLs_old]
            ),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        ),

Comment: Maybe more readable `[link for link_tuple in list for link in link_tuple]`. :)